# Email notification and computer hibernation

Tags: email-integration

I'd like to have my email audio alert me when I leave the computer unattended for over 20 mins.  I work out of the house and am pulled away from the computer occasionally.  I can hear an email audio alert me in another room.  However, the computer seems to 'time out' or hibernate after 20 minutes.  I'll come back to the laptop, hit enter and emails then show up in my inbox.  Anyway to keep the emails coming all day long w/o me hitting the enter key or send/receive in Outlook?  I have 2 msn hotmail accts. coming in.

Comment: Is your computer set to automatically go to sleep or hibernate mode after a length of time?

Answer (score 1):

The best way is for you to set the computer to never sleep, but turn off the display. This way, you can get some power savings (monitor can go to sleep) but the computer stays up, constantly checking for emails. This is assuming you have outlook scheduled to check email every few minutes.

Answer (score 0):

Open the Power Options menu and create a new power plan. Change option to put computer to sleep under the plugged in column to Never.  Select this as your power plan.  You computer should stay active unless the power goes out.